# How to create c# function to convert from groups of ranges of numbers to continues numbers

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

we have 6 groups of 253 machines each one ,
but each group are ranges from machine #2 to machine #254 ,
 and continues IDs to represent each machine.

like in the following table:



Group  Machine        ID 
0      2-254      1-253

1  2-254      254-506

2  2-254      507-759

3  2-254      760-1012

4  2-254      1013-1265

5  2-254      1266-1518

I am looking for a c# easy way to write a function to convert from an ID to a group-machine
 
example: ID 508 is the group #2 , machine #3
 (machine 507 is the 
first machine in group 2 and because it starts with 2 the second machin is machine#3)

and also the other way around 
example: if I get the parameters:group #2 machine#5 ,
 the function has to return the ID 510
How can I do this?
I came with a formula but it didn't work 
any ideas?
thanks

Comment: I find your question confusing. The concept of "machine id" is very vague because you appear to be using the same name for two different things... serialNumber vs groupAndMachineId. Please edit the question to disambuguate these two concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First subtract one from the id to get it zero based, then you can divide it into group and machine, and adjust the machine number to the 2-254 range by adding two:

```
id--;
int group = id / 253;
int machine = (id % 253) + 2;
```

As two separate functions:

```
int GetGroup(int id) {
   return (id - 1) / 253;
}

int GetMachine(int id) {
   return ((id - 1) % 253) + 2;
}
```

To get the id from the group and machine you do the reverse; subtract two from the machine number to make it zero based, merge them, and add one:

```
int GetId(int group, int machine) {
   return group * 253 + (machine - 2) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
function getid ( int g, int m ) {
    return g * (254 - 1 ) + m - 1; 
}
```

I think this is right? Simplified to:

```
function getid ( int g, int m ) {
    return g * 253 + m - 1; 
}
```

IE

```
2 * 253 + 3 = 508
2 * 253 + 5 = 510
```